# Dealing with dates in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

EDIT: changed the whole question sorry, im trying to deal with the mysql DATETIME values,
this is my mysql query:

```
$result="SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m. m.dt
FROM relationships r, notes m, user u
WHERE m.user_id = r.leader
AND r.leader = u.user_id
AND r.listener ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
UNION
SELECT username, picture, id, user_note, reply_id, reply_name, dt
FROM user u, notes b
WHERE u.user_id = b.user_id
AND b.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
AND dt < '".$lastmsg."'
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 10 ";
```

im trying to find rows from this query older than '$lastmsg' and not $lastmsg itself, i thought about using less than but not equal to operator! im not sure if that was stupid!!!

P.S the query works, but its retriving wrong information!!

Comment: Is your `ajax_more.php` returning the content that's already on the page?

Comment: yeh only the first post, and the rest are generated by the database query on `ajax_more.php`. im gonna upload the code now!!

Comment: by the way dt = datetime, thats how the posts are generated!

Comment: Is this posted somewhere public that we can look at it?

Comment: no its on my localhost sorry, i think the problem is with the date, because im taking the dt value of the first post, thats why its it duplicating it when i click more!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only restricting the date on the second half of your UNION.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m.dt
FROM relationships r, notes m, user u
WHERE m.user_id = r.leader
AND r.leader = u.user_id
AND r.listener ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
AND m.dt < '".$lastmsg."'
UNION 
SELECT username, picture, id, user_note, reply_id, reply_name, dt
FROM user u, notes b
WHERE u.user_id = b.user_id
AND b.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
AND dt < '".$lastmsg."'
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Can you run the query directly to confirm that the problem is in the query?  You might want to try running them separately as well to see which part of the UNION is returning the unwanted row.

Comment: yeh thats what im going to try now? :)

Comment: i dnt know whats wrong this is killing me, thers something not logical

Comment: What did the testing turn up?

Comment: its the first query that bring out the unwanted result!!

Comment: If "dt" is a timestamp, and you're trying to get *newer* messages, shouldn't you be looking for rows where "dt" is *greater* than the last timestamp limit?  Time values get bigger as we move into the future. Unless you're Merlin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's working blog-style: newest entries are loaded, hit -more- for older stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the query fragment that looks at the date be

```
AND dt > '".$lastmsg."'
```

?

Comment: the data is retrived and shown, my first default post is shown again when i click MORE!

Comment: Isn't the first post always returned by the query?  It's really not at all clear what you're trying to do. Keep in mind that we don't know what your schema means.

Comment: its exactly like twitter, when you load more updates, you can expect to see the same status message again when you click more!!

Comment: And my point is that you're not correctly interpolating the value of "$lastmsg" into the query - you're passing the string "$lastmsg" instead of the value of the variable.

Comment: i changed what you told me to do! but it still giving me the same duplicate!! it deos not make a difference, thanks for trying

Comment: i think something is wrong with my schema, im going to change my whole question!